# Cassandra scaling storage independently of compute

Tags: cassandra

Is it possible to have Cassandra separate its storage and compute, like Spark allows you to query data on S3 - so compute and storage can be scaled independently?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "compute"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cassandra is a database - you can't separate the 'processing' from the 'storage engine' as fundamentally, Cassandra is designed around the locality of data respective to the instance it belongs to.

In your example, Spark is not a database - it's a cluster compute engine so its architecture is designed around separating compute from storage.

TL;DR - No, you can't scale storage independent of compute, at least in the way you're thinking. You can always add more storage to respective Cassandra instances if your use case allows for it.